# xcode 4.3 can mainstoryboard.storyboard has many view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I hope to show in mainstoryboard.storyboadr inside the two view controllers

view controller 1  =>   label "first view"  button "GO"

view controller 2  =>   label "second View" Button "GO"

click the button "GO" to switch views

Comment: are the view controllers stand-alone or these view controllers are inside a tab bar controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you want an toggle button right? to choose which view controller you want to open after pressing "Go" button? if this is so then you have to use UISegmentedControll try to find it in object Library..

Comment: so if you can't deal it with yourself you wanna see that : http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-segmented-controluisegmentedcontrol-tutorial/